# What is the total observational energy of the universe?

Tags: energy

Based on what is measurable, how much energy is in the universe if the initial time is the big bang and the final time is the present?

Comment: This question does something worse than the linked question: This question assumes we can somehow observe the total energy of the universe. That said, I too marked this as a duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, let us all know when you have built a big-bang calorimeter!